# How to send an Email confirmation after customer signup

Tags: magento2, customer, customer-account

I need your help for the customer registration process.

I need to create functionality as during account creation will be to require users to confirm /activate their account by clicking a link in an email sent to a valid email address.

As default feature available in Magento, in configuration CUSTOMERS > Customer Configuration there is a flag which is "required email confirmation" but this flag available in web site level.

I want to achieve this using store level, is there any possibility to implement using store level?

Also after sending email to customer there I have to show popup for customer